# How to handle a silent push as 'silent' when app is closed or in the background? (Android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app receives push notifications when app is closed and is in the background.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream
as this document said,

> When your app is in the background, Android directs messages with
>   notification to the system tray. A user click on a notification opens
>   the app launcher by default.

But the problem is that I can't handle silent push when my app is in the background or closed. I got push notification that doesn't have a title, it's empty message but it goes off!
It's not a silent push at all.

How can I receive my silent push message as silent?

Comment: my recommendation: use fcm, as the link also states out, and send fcm messages without notification data in payload.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Hi, Thanks for your comment. Then, it's impossible to make it as silent when the app is in the background with using gcm?

Comment: I must confess, I have no experience with gcm, but fcm. I've no idea if they are any different. But I assume, basically it should be kind of the same. But I can't do any suggestions if it is possible or not. Sorry

Comment: @JacksOnF1re OK. but many Thanks!

Comment: @JacksOnF1re I'm gonna try this. It seems that it would work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555653/push-silent-notification-through-gcm-to-android-ios